# How to precache all assets files in nuxt.js using the workbox-webpack-plugin?

Tags: nuxt.js, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

just I'd like to precache dist files `(dist/_nuxt/*)` of my nuxt project,
but when I run nuxt.js PWA application, I can not find precache list in Browser > Application > Cache > Cache Storage.

How can i precache all the assets files generated by webpack?

```
"@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.2"
"nuxt": "^2.14.0"
"workbox-webpack-plugin":"^5.1.4"
```

```
new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
swSrc: path.join(process.cwd(), "/static/sw.js"),
swDest: path.join(process.cwd(), "/dist/sw.js"),});
```